# LaTeX table formatting for A4 page readability

Tags: tables, adjustbox, scalebox

I'm looking to include a table in a document on a single page with A4 size, ensuring that the text remains readable. I attempted to use \scalebox, but it resulted in the text becoming too small and altering the width and height of the box. Since I'm relatively new to LaTeX, I find myself a bit stuck and would appreciate any suggestions or guidance you could offer on how to achieve this. Thank you!

```
\tiny
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{0pt}}  llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline                    
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textbf{Monetary Policy} \\
1) Monetary Authority  Loans Through the Asset Backed Commercial Paper Money \\  Market Mutual Fund Liquidity Facility  AMLF  and Money Market Mutual Fund \\ Liquidity Facility  MMLF   Asset  Level Lag 1 \\ 
2) Monetary Authority  Depository Institution Loans N E C  to Other Financial Business \\ Commercial Paper Funding Facility LLC   Asset  Transactions Lag 1 \\

\textbf{International Finance - Government} \\
1) Rest of the World  U S  Government Loans Excluding Capital Subscriptions and \\ Contributions to International Financial Institutions and the IMF  Liability  Revaluation Lag 0 \\ 
2) Rest of the World  Other U S  Reserve Assets  Other Claims  Liability  Transactions Lag 0 \\ 
3) Rest of the World  U S  Government Loans Excluding Capital Subscriptions and \\ Contributions to International Financial Institutions and the IMF  Liability  Revaluation Lag 1 \\ 
4) Rest of the World  U S  Government Loans Excluding Capital Subscriptions and \\ Contributions to International Financial Institutions and the IMF  Liability  Revaluation Lag 4 \\ 
5) Rest of the World  Other U S  Reserve Assets  Other Claims  Liability  Revaluation Lag 0 \\ 

\textbf{Domestic Finance - Private} \\ 
1) Government Sponsored Enterprises  Equity Capital of Farm Credit System  Transactions Lag 3 \\ 
2) Pension Funds  Corporate Equities  Asset  Transactions Lag 2 \\ 
3) Security Brokers and Dealers  Payables to Customer and Rest of the World \\ Noncustomers  Free Credit  Margin Deposits  and Other Payables   Liability  \\ Transactions Lag 4 \\ 
4) Government Sponsored Enterprises  Corporate Equities Held by Freddie Mac  Asset \\  Level Lag 0 \\ 
5) Private Depository Institutions  Total Time and Savings Deposits  Liability  \\ Transactions Lag 1 \\ 
6) Nonprofit Organizations  Municipal Securities  Sum of Holders   Liability  FWTW   \\ Transactions Lag 4 \\ 
7) Other Financial Corporations and Insurance Companies and Pension Funds  Net \\ Claims on Nonfinancial Businesses and Households and Nonprofit Organizations  \\ Asset  FWTW   Transactions Lag 4 \\ 

\textbf{Recession} \\
1) Government Sponsored Enterprises  Equity Capital of Farm Credit System  Transactions Lag 4 \\ 
2) NBER based Recession Indicators for the United States from the Period following \\ the Peak through the Trough Lag 2 \\ 
3) NBER based Recession Indicators for the United States from the Peak through the \\ Period preceding the Trough Lag 3 \\ 
4) OECD based Recession Indicators for the United States from the Peak through the \\ Trough Lag 2 \\ 
5) OECD based Recession Indicators for the United States from the Peak through the Trough 1 Lag 2 \\ 

\textbf{Unemployment and Wages} \\
1) Employment Level   Agriculture and Related Industries  Wage and Salary Workers Lag 1 \\ 
2) Unemployment Rate   Nonagriculture  Private Wage and Salary Workers Lag 3 \\ 

\textbf{Domestic Finance - Government} \\
1) State and Local Government Employee Defined Benefit Retirement Funds  Total Time \\ and Savings Deposits  Asset  Transactions Lag 0 \\ 
2) State and Local Government Employee Defined Benefit Retirement Funds  Total Time \\ and Savings Deposits  Asset  Transactions Lag 1 \\ 
3) Total Consumer Credit Owned by Depository Institutions  Flow Lag 1 \\ 
4) Domestic Financial Sectors  Net Saving Including Foreign Earnings Retained Abroad \\ and CCAdj Less Net Capital Transfers Paid  Other Than for Financial Stabilization \\ Program   Transactions Lag 1 \\ 
5) General Government  Other Accounts Payable Including SDR Allocations  Liability  \\ IMA   Revaluation Lag 4 \\ 
6) State and Local Governments  Foreign Bonds  Asset  FWTW   Transactions Lag 2 \\ 
7) Domestic Financial Sectors  Net Saving Including Foreign Earnings Retained Abroad \\ and CCAdj Less Net Capital Transfers Paid  Other Than for Financial Stabilization \\ Program   Transactions Lag 2 \\ 

\textbf{International Finance - Private} \\
1) Households and Nonprofit Organizations  Commercial and Multifamily Residential \\ Mortgages  Asset  Transactions Lag 1 \\ 
2) Rest of the World  Corporate Bonds Issued by Netherlands Antillean Financial \\ Subsidiaries of U S  Corporations  Asset  Revaluation Lag 4 \\ 
3) Households and Nonprofit Organizations  Commercial and Multifamily Residential \\ Mortgages  Asset  Transactions Lag 2 \\ 
4) Pension Funds  Security Repurchase Agreements Issued by the Rest of the World  \\ Asset  FWTW   Revaluation Lag 4 \\ 
5) Domestic Financial Sectors  Insurance  Pension and Standardized Guarantee Schemes  \\ Asset  IMA   Revaluation Lag 4 \\ 
6) Rest of the World  Debt Securities and Negotiable Certificates of Deposit Issued \\ by Financial Corporations  Asset  FWTW   Transactions Lag 1 \\ 
7) Private Pension Funds  Security Repurchase Agreements  Asset  Transactions Lag 3 \\ 
8) Private Pension Funds  Security Repurchase Agreements  Asset  Transactions Lag 2 \\ 
9) Holding Companies  Security Repurchase Agreements Issued by the Rest of the World \\  Asset  FWTW   Transactions Lag 0 \\ 
10) Rest of the World  Corporate Bonds Issued by Netherlands Antillean Financial \\ Subsidiaries of U S  Corporations  Asset  Transactions Lag 0 \\ 

\textbf{Housing and Mortgages} \\
1) Federal Government  One to Four Family Residential Mortgages Held by RTC  Asset \\ Level Lag 1 \\ 
2) Federal Government  One to Four Family Residential Mortgages  Asset  Transactions \\ Lag 4 \\ 
3) Federal Government  One to Four Family Residential Mortgages Held by Public Housing \\ Administration  PHA   Asset  Transactions Lag 4 \\ 
4) Federal Government  One to Four Family Residential Mortgages Held by RTC  Asset \\ Level Lag 3 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Selected economic variables by SCAD regression} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might find some ideas [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/47927). But first of all, why do you define 42 `l` columns if you only use one? Why do you use a `tabular` at all? Anyways, the simplest hot fix to this would probably be to replace the column defintion (in the mandatory argument to the `tabular` environment) with just `@{} p{\linewidth} @{}`.

Comment: only use `\scalebox` on tables as a last resort, and even then try to avoid it.

Comment: `llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll`   means you are specifying a table of 41 columns, each set to the natural width of the text, with no line breaking. That is not going to fit in most pages.

Comment: I understand. I changed it to just one column with using just one l. Now I try to make the font smaller inside the table smaller. However, somehow this does not work. I only can change the size of just one line.

Comment: Just adding \small does not work as done here:

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\small
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{0pt}}  l} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline                    
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textbf{Monetary Policy} \\
1) Monetary Authority  Loans Through the Asset Backed Commercial Paper Money \\  Market Mutual Fund Liquidity Facility  AMLF  and Money Market Mutual Fund \\ -......

Comment: if you only want 1 column, why are you using a table at all? This just seems to be an enumerated list, numbered by habd (which you should almost never do in latex) I would remove all the font size, tabular and adjustbox markup and just have a series of `enumerate` enviornments

Comment: Don't use an `l` column, but a `p{\linewidth}` column which will automatically break lines. You can additionally decrease the font size with `\small` or `\footnotesize`. If the text body is not very tight, this should work. If not, please show a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we know more about your document set up, the paper size, margins etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{...}` that comes after `\begin{tabular}` is the column specification: it tells lateX what columns are coming in your table.  `l` means a left adjusted column with no line breaks.  You're claiming that there are 42 such columns, but you only ever use 1 column.  That looks strange, but doesn't really cause the problem.  The problem is that `l` doesn't allow for line breaks, so you have to introduce all of those arbitrary `\\`  line breaks.  Instead, you can use `p{\linewidth}` to say the column is the width of your page, and TeX will automatically figure out the line breaks.  But if it's only one column, it's not really a table, and you shouldn't use tabular (you can still use `\begin{table}` if you want to call it a table, but don't use tabular).  But we'll introduce some columns.

As you noticed, `\adjustbox` and `\scalebox` will destroy your font sizing and aspect ratio, and should be avoided.  I've also changed the `[!htpb]` into `[p]`, since the table is so large that's really the only possibility.

The general idea of designing a table is if you're repeating information, you should try to move it to a better location.  The big one in this case is that every row is ending with "Lag #", suggesting that "Lag" should be a new column.  The first column can now change to the `X` type of `tabularx`, which means that the lag column will be sized for its widest item, and the `X` column will take the rest of the width.

Some of the entries in a category start with the same text.  I've moved that text to the header for that category.  Some of your entries are identical except for different lags.  I combined those into a single entry, and put both lags in the lag column.

I don't see a reason for the leading numbers, so I removed them.

Doing all of this (and some overly agressive abbreviating) allows me to change `\tiny` up to `\footnotesize`, and Table 1 fits onto a single a4 page with geometry's default margins (you really should have told us what your margins are).  If I were you, I think I would stop there, and undo some of my abbreviations.

We can do a *bit* better by moving the categories to a new column, and nesting some `tabularx` for the very repetitive "Recession" and "Mortgage" entries (and the Netherlands Antillean entries).  That saves us a line or two, so that we can get up to `\small` and Table 2.

Other items:

- I've rearranged several categories to move similar variables next to each other.
- You've capitalized far too many words.  I undid most of that.
- `-` is for a hyphen.  If you want a dash, you should use `---`.  And `--` for a range of numbers.
- I've introduced `booktabs` and its rules.
- The usual advice is that a table's caption should go above, and a figure's caption should go below.

The code and its result:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[p]\footnotesize
\caption{Selected economic variables by SCAD regression} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} X c @{} } \toprule
\textbf{Monetary Policy} --- Monetary Authority & Lag \\
Loans through the asset backed commercial paper money market mutual fund liquidity facility  AMLF \& MMLF   asset  level & 1 \\ 
Depository inst loans NEC to other fin business commercial paper funding facility LLC asset txns & 1 \\\midrule
\textbf{International Finance --- Govt} --- Non-US \\
US govt loans excl capital subscriptions \& contributions to international fin insts \& the IMF  liability  reval & 0,1,4 \\ 
Other US  reserve assets  other claims  liability  txns & 0 \\ 
Other US  reserve assets  other claims  liability  reval & 0 \\ \midrule
\textbf{Domestic Finance --- Private} \\ 
Govt sponsored enterprises  equity capital of farm credit system  txns & 3 \\ 
Govt sponsored enterprises  corporate equities held by Freddie Mac  asset level & 0 \\ 
Pension funds  corporate equities  asset  txns & 2 \\ 
Security brokers \& dealers  payables to customer \& non-US noncustomers  free credit  margin deposits  \& other payables   liability  txns & 4 \\ 
Private depository insts  total time \& savings deposits  liability  txns & 1 \\ 
Nonprofit orgs  municipal securities  sum of holders   liability  FWTW   txns & 4 \\ 
Other fin corps \& insurance comps \& pension funds  net claims on nonfin businesses \& households \& nonprofit orgs  asset  FWTW   txns & 4 \\ \midrule
\textbf{Recession} \\
Govt sponsored enterprises  equity capital of farm credit system  txns & 4 \\
NBER based recession indicators for the US from the period following the peak through the trough & 2 \\ 
NBER based recession indicators for the US from the peak through the period preceding the trough & 3 \\ 
OECD based recession indicators for the US from the peak through the trough & 2 \\ 
OECD based recession indicators for the US from the peak through the trough 1 & 2 \\ \midrule
\textbf{Unemployment \& Wages} \\
Employment level   ag \& related industries  wage \& salary workers & 1 \\ 
Unemployment rate   nonag  private wage \& salary workers & 3 \\ \midrule
\textbf{Domestic Finance --- Govt} \\
State \& local govt employee defined ben rtrmnt funds  total time \& savings deposits  asset  txns & 0,1 \\ 
Total consumer credit owned by depository insts  flow & 1 \\ 
Gen govt  other accounts payable incl SDR allocations  liability  IMA   reval & 4 \\ 
State \& local govts  foreign bonds  asset  FWTW   txns & 2 \\ 
Domestic fin sectors  net saving incl foreign earnings retained abroad \& CCAdj less net capital txfrs paid  other than for fin stabilization program   txns & 1,2 \\ \midrule
\textbf{International Finance --- Private} \\
Households \& nonprofit orgs  commercial \& multifam res mortgages  asset  txns & 1,2 \\ 
Non-US  corporate bonds issued by Netherlands Antillean fin subsidiaries of US  corps  asset  reval & 4 \\ 
Pension funds  security repurchase agreements issued by the non-US  asset  FWTW   reval & 4 \\ 
Domestic fin sectors  insurance  pension \& standardized guarantee schemes asset  IMA   reval & 4 \\ 
Non-US  debt securities \& negotiable certificates of deposit issued by fin corps  asset  FWTW   txns & 1 \\ 
Private pension funds security repurchase agreements  asset  txns & 3,2 \\ 
Holding comps  security repurchase agreements issued by the non-US asset  FWTW   txns & 0 \\ 
Non-US  corporate bonds issued by Netherlands Antillean fin subsidiaries of US  corps  asset  txns & 0 \\ \midrule
\textbf{Housing \& Mortgages} --- Fed Govt 1--4 Fam Res Mortgages \\
Asset  txns & 4 \\ 
Held by public housing admin  PHA   asset  txns & 4 \\ 
Held by RTC  asset level & 1,3 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[p]\small
\caption{Selected economic variables by SCAD regression} 
\newlength{\firstcolwidth}
\setlength{\firstcolwidth}{2.1cm}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} p{\firstcolwidth} X c @{} } \toprule
Category & Variable & Lag \\\midrule
\multirow[t]{2}{\firstcolwidth}{Monetary Policy --- Monetary Authority}
& Loans through the asset backed commercial paper money market mutual fund liquidity facility  AMLF \& MMLF   asset  level & 1 \\ 
& Depository inst loans NEC  to other fin business commercial paper funding facility LLC   asset  txns & 1 \\\midrule
\multirow[t]{4}{\firstcolwidth}{International Finance --- Govt --- Non-US}
& US govt loans excl capital subscriptions \& contributions to international fin insts \& the IMF  liability  reval & 0,1,4 \\ 
& Other US  reserve assets  other claims  liability  txns & 0 \\ 
& Other US  reserve assets  other claims  liability  reval & 0 \\ \midrule
\multirow[t]{7}{\firstcolwidth}{Domestic Finance --- Private}
& Govt sponsored enterprises  equity capital of farm credit system  txns & 3 \\ 
& Govt sponsored enterprises  corporate equities held by Freddie Mac  asset level & 0 \\ 
& Nonprofit orgs  municipal securities  sum of holders   liability  FWTW   txns & 4 \\ 
& Pension funds  corporate equities  asset  txns & 2 \\ 
& Private depository insts  total time \& savings deposits  liability  txns & 1 \\ 
& Security brokers \& dealers  payables to customer \& non-US noncustomers  free credit  margin deposits  \& other payables   liability  txns & 4 \\ 
& Other fin corps \& insurance comps \& pension funds  net claims on nonfin businesses \& households \& nonprofit orgs  asset  FWTW   txns & 4 \\ \midrule
\multirow[t]{5}{\firstcolwidth}{Recession}
& Govt sponsored enterprises  equity capital of farm credit system  txns & 4 \\ 
& \multirow{4}{*}{%
 {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{} p{3cm} X }
  \multirow[t]{4}{3cm}{Recession indicators for the US ...}
  & NBER, post peak through trough \\
  & NBER, peak through pre trough \\
  & OECD, peak through trough \\
  & OECD, peak through trough 1 \\
 \end{tabularx}}
}
& 2 \\ & & 3 \\ & & 2 \\ & & 2 \\\midrule
\multirow[t]{2}{\firstcolwidth}{Unemployment \& Wages}
& Employment level ag \& related industries  wage \& salary workers & 1 \\ 
& Unemployment rate nonag  private wage \& salary workers & 3 \\ \midrule
\multirow[t]{6}{\firstcolwidth}{Domestic Finance --- Govt}
& State \& local govt employee defined ben rtrmnt funds  total time \& savings deposits  asset  txns & 0,1 \\ 
& State \& local govts  foreign bonds  asset  FWTW   txns & 2 \\ 
& Total consumer credit owned by depository insts  flow & 1 \\ 
& Gen govt  other accounts payable incl SDR allocations  liability  IMA   reval & 4 \\ 
& Domestic fin sectors  net saving incl foreign earnings retained abroad \& CCAdj less net capital txfrs paid  other than for fin stabilization program   txns & 1,2 \\ \midrule
\multirow[t]{9}{\firstcolwidth}{International Finance --- Private}
& Households \& nonprofit orgs  commercial \& multifam res mortgages  asset  txns & 1,2 \\ 
& Non-US  debt securities \& negotiable certificates of deposit issued by fin corps  asset  FWTW   txns & 1 \\ 
& Domestic fin sectors  insurance  pension \& standardized guarantee schemes asset  IMA   reval & 4 \\ 
& Holding comps  security repurchase agreements issued by the non-US asset  FWTW   txns & 0 \\ 
& Pension funds  security repurchase agreements issued by the non-US  asset  FWTW   reval & 4 \\ 
& Private pension funds security repurchase agreements  asset  txns & 3,2 \\ 
& \multirow{2}{*}{{%
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{} X l }
  \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Non-US  corporate bonds issued by Netherlands Antillean fin subsidiaries of US  corps  asset ...}
  & reval \\ & txns
 \end{tabularx}
}}
& 4 \\ & & 0 \\
\midrule
\multirow[t]{3}{\firstcolwidth}{Housing \& Mortgages}
& \multirow{3}{*}{%
{\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{} p{2.8cm} X }
 \multirow[t]{3}{\linewidth}{Fed Govt 1--4 Fam Res Mortgages}
& Asset  txns \\ 
& Held by public housing admin  PHA   asset  txns \\ 
& Held by RTC  asset level
\end{tabularx} }}
& 4 \\ & & 4 \\ & & 1,3 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table 1 output]

[image: Table 2 output]